# JMeter assertion for a API response which contains [] or string "transaction"

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins

How can we assert an API response which contains [] or "transaction"?

Jmeter Assertion should pass if it contains any of the below response
Response 1: [] (only empty square brackets)
or
Response 2: contains string "transaction" as part of response

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest is going for [Response Assertion](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Response_Assertion) configured like:

[image]

It will pass in 2 cases:

- when response body will contain `[]`
- or when response body will contain `transaction`

if response body won't contain any of these - the assertion will fail.

More information: [What Are JMeter Response Assertions?](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/response-assertions-in-jmeter)